# WP7 Moving Objects on a Map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, bing-maps

I have an image on a Windows Phone 7 MapLayer on a map control that I need to be able to move. It would be great to transform it (animate) but not a must.

So lets say i have a MapLayer called `pLayer` and I add an image to it:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("XXX.png"));
pLayer.AddChild(img, new GeoCoordinate(LAT, LNG) );
```

how do i move its location after i've added it to the MapLayer `[pLayer]`?

Can I access the `pLayer.Childeren[KEY].Location` or something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a simpler method, but one optioin is to remove the object from the layer, and then re-add it in the new location.

```
Image img = ...some image loaded at a location on the map in the above code;
var ll = new GeoCoordinate(LAT, LNG);
Layer.Children.Remove(img);
Layer.AddChild(img, ll);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378588/bing-map-silverlight-binding-for-moving-target) also give a somewhat more complicated solution using binding.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to create a Canvas the same size as the Map control, then add that as a child of a map layer and add the Image as a child of the Canvas. This should then give you the ability to position the image absolutely anywhere on the canvas by handling touch gestures. The GestureService.GestureListener in the [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) provides events that make this easier.

Comment: But with this proposal, you lose the enormous advantage of automatic geolocating any UIElement you put on the map.